# Replacement PPA for Ubuntu Precise

Tags: apt, ppa

Today, when executing `apt-get update` after adding the R language repositories to `apt`, I received the following erros

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net http/ppa/ubuntu/precise Sources          
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net http/ppa/ubuntu/main Sources             
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net http/ppa/ubuntu/precise i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net http/ppa/ubuntu/main i386 Packages       
  404  Not Found
```

From the paths listed, they are from the Ubuntu Precise distribution, which is a LTS version.  To fix these errors, what are the replacement paths?

I found

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ppa/lxc-lts/ubuntu/dists/precise/
```

but would like to confirm that this is the replacement path for the packages.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` as it appears that you have malformed PPA entries, which is probably the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources available, here is a complete list of cran mirrors here:

http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Here is a good example of the install:

http://livesoncoffee.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/installing-r-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: I think you misread my question.  The ppas listed are not part of CRAN, but Canonical Ubuntu itself.

Comment: @Jason PPAs are "Private Package Archives" and in no way "part of Canonical Ubuntu itself". Why don't you ask the maintainer of the archive?